# How do I sort a dictionary by a value when the value is 3 levels deep?

Tags: python, python-2.7, sorting, dictionary

Let's say that the following dictionary is the output of the previous code:

```
{  
   '1':{  
      'json':{  
         'stuff2':[  
            '123',
            '234',
            '345'
         ],
         'region':'APAC'
      },
      'stuff':{  
         'search1':'1231245132512',
         'search2':'235346262346'
      }
   },
   '2':{  
      'json':{  
         'stuff2':[  
            '123',
            '234',
            '345'
         ],
         'region':'EMEA'
      },
      'stuff':{  
         'search1':'1231245132512',
         'search2':'235346262346'
      }
   },
   '3':{  
      'json':{  
         'stuff2':[  
            '123',
            '234',
            '345'
         ],
         'region':'AMER'
      },
      'stuff':{  
         'search1':'1231245132512',
         'search2':'235346262346'
      }
   }
}
```

The code I have is currently assigning a generator to a variable and then using that generator in a for loop:

`runs = (unimportantFunc(x,y,z) for x,y in dict.items())`

`for i in runs:...`

I need to be able to order the for loop by region from the `dict[x]]['json']['region']` but short of running an entire second for loop over the dictionary, setting them into their own nested lists, and then doing a double for loop, I can't think of any way to order them. I was reading some documentation on how to sort by values, but I can't figure out how to do that when the value is nested 3 deep.

I want the run to be ordered to run `dict[x]]['json']['region'] = APAC` first, EMEA second and AMER 3rd.

We're using Python 2.7, so I won't be able to use anything that exists in Python 3.

Comment: Why do you think it's different when the value is 3 levels deep? Just use `i['x']['json']['region']` when sorting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
sorted(dict.keys(), key=lambda k: dict[k]['json']['region'])
```

This will return a list of your keys sorted by region:

```
['3', '1', '2']
```